# Building an array from a MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I hope it's the heat, this is the second question today and it's one problem after the other. Relatively simple stuff...

I have this query ...

```
while ($resultV = mysql_fetch_assoc($metQueryViews)) { $allViews[] = $resultV; }
```

The date it's getting is:-

```
date        Count
NULL         6
14-5-2009   12
15-5-2009   21
26-6-2009   18
29-6-2009   61
```

I'm trying to build an array, that reads out

```
"14-5-2009" = > "12"
```

But, the above while statement produces what seems to be a multi-dimensional array or sommet, which has the field name => value.

Thoughts on a little post card are most welcome.

Comment: Can you post your query or at least a list of columns you expect, that would make it easier to give you a certain answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$allViews[] = array($resultV["date"] => $resultV["count"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$allViews = array();
while (list($date, $count) = mysql_fetch_row($metQueryViews)) {

    $allViews[$date] = $count;
}
```